# не открывает приложение django urls

Tags: python, django, soap

В проекте есть приложение soap, но оно не открывается по ссылке, которую указываю в urls

project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('soap/', include('soap.urls'))
]
```

soap/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap12
from spyne.server.django import DjangoView

from soap.views import hello_world_service, app, HelloWorldService


urlpatterns = [
    path('hello_world/', hello_world_service),
    path('say_hello/', DjangoView.as_view(
        services=[HelloWorldService], tns='spyne.examples.django',
        in_protocol=Soap12(validator='lxml'), out_protocol=Soap12())),
    path('say_hello_not_cached/', DjangoView.as_view(
        services=[HelloWorldService], tns='spyne.examples.django',
        in_protocol=Soap12(validator='lxml'), out_protocol=Soap12(),
        cache_wsdl=False)),
    path('api/', DjangoView.as_view(application=app)),
]
```

При открытии mysite.com/soap, выдает 404
но mysite.com/admin открывается как надо

Answer (score 0):

удали soap/ чтобы было

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('soap.urls'))
]
```

здесь ты говоришь, что при переходе из главной страницы, ты будешь попадать в soap.urls

для примера такой html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'hello_world' %}">ссылка</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'say_hello' %}">ссылка</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'say_hello_not_cached' %}">ссылка</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'api' %}">ссылка</a></li>
      </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

при переходе из главной страницы по ссылке hello_world будет mysite.com/hello_world, а т.к ты указываешь soap/ django его не видит, соответственно при подключении нескольких приложений, всегда оставляй вначале пустое значение в кавычках, там будет url из url приложения, типа:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('soap.urls')),
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('', include('app2.urls'))
]
```